# Problem start xampp on ubuntu 19.04

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, xampp

I installed xampp and when I try to start the service, MySQL doesn't start only apache and proFTPD

and I was getting this error

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
```

After some search I found that there is an already running MySQL service other than xampp's

so currently everytime I start my xampp I have to stop the MySQL service first using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

then

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

is there a way I can remove this service completely so xampp can be started without my having to stop the service first before starting xampp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If MySQL database is not required in your setup you can disable it permanently with:

```
sudo systemctl disable mysql
```

But if you wish to remove it (keep in mind that **your MySQL databases will be deleted**), then first you should check what version of MySQL is installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep -E "^ii.*(mysql|mariadb)-server"
```

Then remove these packages with:

```
sudo apt remove mariadb-server*
```

or

```
sudo apt remove mysql-server*
```

depending on what version you have.